# How to pass dynamic parameters to rest api in android when using viewmodel

Tags: android, retrofit, viewmodel

I am fetching news details from News Api site. I am using ViewModel architecture so that the device does not fetch the results when orientation changes.

As per various turorials i am able to fetch the result to a recyclerview using retrofit and viewmodel buy giving static parameters as query to the rest api.

```java
private void loadTopHeadlines() {
        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<TopHeadlinesResponse> response = apiInterface.getTopHeadlines("in", 20, 1,
                "api_key");
        response.enqueue(new Callback<TopHeadlinesResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TopHeadlinesResponse> call, Response<TopHeadlinesResponse> response) {
                topHeadlinesResponse.setValue(response.body().getArticles());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TopHeadlinesResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see in the ViewModel class that is created the method getTopHeadlines() uses static parameters. How do i change it to dynamic parameters.

Static parameter

```java
Call<TopHeadlinesResponse> response = apiInterface.getTopHeadlines("in", 20, 1,
                "api_key");
```

Dynamic parameter

```java
Call<TopHeadlinesResponse> response = apiInterface.getTopHeadlines(dynamic, dynamic, dynamic,
                "api_key");
```

Comment: where do those dynamic parameters come from?

Comment: the first parameter is based on users current location("in") the second and third parameters are page size and page count.

Comment: great, are they passed from view? viewmodel?

Comment: passed from viewmodel

Answer (score 1):

So basically your method should accept those parameters, e.g.:

```
private void loadHeadlines(String stringValue, int number, int otherNumer)
//...do some stuff
Call<TopHeadlinesResponse> response = apiInterface.getTopHeadlines(stringValue, number, otherNumber, "api_key");
//rest stays the same
}
```